# How do you pass a component into the attribute of a component in React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have `SplitPane` component class with attributes `body` and `side`. I also have a `Table` component class I'm trying to insert but I keep getting an error.

`<SplitPane side='hi' body=<MyTable /> />`

will return

`JSXAttribute expected node to be of a type ["JSXElement","StringLiteral","JSXExpressionContainer"] but instead got "CallExpression"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap it in curly braces and remove the JSX. Just pretend it's a normal variable.

```
<SplitPane side='hi' body={MyTable} />
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `<SplitPane side='hi' body={<MyTable />} />`